# Copy Filters from one PowerPivot PivotTable to another

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot, vba

I have 2 PivotTables that were created from PowerPivot connections. I would like the second PivotTable to change based on a selection the user makes on the first PivotTable. I have some VBA background, so you don't need to write the whole code but point me to the right functions/structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use slicers, you can simply link both tables to the same set of slicers. You can even have multiple copies of each slicer.

It's the same in all versions of Excel since 2010. [Here's a link.](https://www.sageintelligence.com/excel-tips-tricks/2012/09/sharing-slicers-between-pivottables/)

Edit: Adding information from my comment below here.

You can use this technique even when you're explicitly using a filter on the pivot table, whether by adding a field to the Filters section, or by putting that field on the row/column labels and then limiting the selection based on that row/column header drop down. You can mix and match these as well, with Pivot1 having the field in question in the Filters section, and Pivot2 having the field in the Rows section.

Just create your two pivot tables as normal, and then connect both to the same slicer. This slicer can be hidden on another sheet that is not displayed to the end users. This solution is much more expedient than the VBA solutions I've seen.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @greggyb. Can't use slicers as one of my field has atleast a 1000 values, so I'm using a report filter so the user can use the search function in it

Comment: No worries. Put the filter onto each pivot table like normal. Then make a slicer on the same field and attach it to both pivot tables. Then just hide it on another sheet that is also hidden in the workbook. It does this for you Filter 1 <=> Slicer <=> Filter 2